# How to deploy multiple shiny apps at the same time?

Tags: rstudio, shiny

I've have multiple subdirectories containing some Shiny apps.
Here is the directory structure :

```
/Documents/shinyapps/app1/ui.R
/Documents/shinyapps/app1/Server.R
/Documents/shinyapps/app2/ui.R
/Documents/shinyapps/app2/Server.R
```

It looks like it's not possible to deploy multiple shiny apps at the same time using RStudio. I'm using Rstudio: Version 1.0.44

I've tried with this structure as well but app2 is not found:

```
Documents/shinyapps/app1/ui.R
/Documents/shinyapps/app1/Server.R
/Documents/shinyapps/app1/app2/ui.R
/Documents/shinyapps/app1/app2/Server.R
```

[image: Example of deploy]

Comment: Best answer for now : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/lMgdBIVP5ps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using shiny server.
You can download shiny server and install it in your Linux machine.
Then you can go to the deployment folder (which is usually `/srv/shiny-server` but can be changed in the config files).

You can either:

create a directory structure in the folder and refer to each app with the different file paths.

Or:

Create an index.html file and arrange your shiny apps to fit in a custom made landing page of your liking. The easiest way is to use iframes.